# How to construct a bootstrap dropdown list with static placeholder and custom icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm very new to web development and I'm trying to construct a dropdown list that contains a static, slightly greyed out, placeholder and a custom icon.  When an item in the drop down list is selected, the text of the selected item should be displayed on the dropdown.  I have tried a few different approaches and the code below gets me somewhat close but still not exactly what I'm looking for and I'm also not even sure if this is the right approach.

Is there a way to create a bootstrap (or non bootstrap) dropdown with a static placeholder, custom icon, and updates display text to user selection?

```html
<div>
  <label type = "button">Fruit</label>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Apple</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blueberry</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pear</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider this snippet as a possible answer.

```js
$(".dropdown-item").click(function(){
  $(".dropdown-item").removeClass("active");
  $("#dropdownMenuLabel").text(this.innerHTML);
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="text-dark">Fruit</span> <span id="dropdownMenuLabel"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Apple</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blueberry</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pear</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way you can do is by using [Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com), [Material Icons](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline) or any other icon toolkit and use their CDN.

It will look something like this

```
<!-- Add this line to use Google's Material Icon -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then just add it to your code.

```
<!-- Using CDN -->
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
   <!-- This will show a favorite icon -->
   <i class="material-icons">favorite</i> 
   Apple
</a>
```

You can check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/) for more detailed information